# Removing the border in search bar at the navigation title

Tags: ios, swift

my nav bar look like the image attached below. How do I remove the black border?

[image]

And my code to generate that is as follow

```
    var searchBar : UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(-5, 0, 320, 44))
    searchBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
    searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal


    var searchBarView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 44))
    searchBarView.autoresizingMask = nil
    searchBarView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
    searchBarView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

   searchBar.delegate = self;
   searchBarView.addSubview(searchBar)
```

Comment: `searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0` doesn't work?

Comment: perhaps also do what you did on the view, with the `borderColor`

Comment: it works! do you want to add it as an answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps also do what you did on the view,

```
searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
```